# Application Pool Identity Windows Server 2008R2 Acces is Denied to network shared folder on Windows Server 2003

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003, applicationpoolidentity

I have application that is hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2. Application is running under IIS Application Pool Identity. When i try to import some xml file through application to network shared folder (which is on windows server 2003) i have a message "Acces is denied to....".

I know i can fix this by having same user on both machines, and running application pool with that user instead of Application Pool Identity, but that's not ok for me :(

I also gave all sorts of permisions to all sorts of users (IIS_USRS IIS AppPool*Application Pool Name*, etc..) but nothing helped.

MY QUESTION :

Is it possible to write in network shared folder (on windows server 2003 without IIS - file server) through application which is running unser IIS Application Pool Identity ?

THANKS IN ADVANCE !!!!

Answer (score 0):

When using the built-in application pool identity, any calls across the network are made using the computer account. You should be able to assign the computer account rights to the network share and NTFS to accomplish this.